# Python django-oauth-toolkit client_credentials allows anything to go through and doesn't add user to the token

Tags: django, django-oauth-toolkit

I'm using django-oauth-toolkit and I can't figure out why when I use client_credentials, I can literally insert any username/password combo and they always return a token
even if the username/password combo is nowhere in the database.

This is my postman request body:
[image: Postman Request]

On the admin portal, I don't even see the user selected under "user":
[image: Access Tokens on Admin Portal]

How do I only allow valid username/password combos to return an access token and how do I attach a user to an access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use 'resource owner password based' grant type, instead of 'client credentials'.